# how to generalize option remove in jq

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

To replace labels with variables in the following

```
$("label[for='c1pick'] .ui-btn-text").html($("#c1introdukt").val())
```

one has to define the variable

```
whichc="c1"
 whichintrodukt = whichc+"introdukt";
```

and do this trick (you can see two different ways: complete and partial predefinition):

```
$("label[for=" + whichc + 'pick' + "] .ui-btn-text").html($("#" + whichintrodukt).val())
```

Now, how to replicate it in

```
$("#choosec1 option").remove();
```

?
The following does not work:

```
whichc="c1"
$("#" +"choose" + whichc + "option").remove();
```

Removing parentheses from option does not do either. Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Missing space**

```
 "option").remove();
  ^--- Missing here //  which is --> "#choosec1option"
```

Should be

```
 " option").remove(); // you are looking for --> "#choosec1 option"
```

This should do

```
whichc="c1"
$("#" +"choose" + whichc + " option").remove();
```

Comment: Yes, space was missing. TY!!